# Is there a better way to implement this algorithm to return a list of all combinations of letter order of a word?

Tags: clojure

I remember in the past writing a Python program that did this same thing. I remember thinking the algorithm as clever, but now trying to implement it from memory in Clojure I'm having some issues.

I'm pretty new to Clojure, so I know that I'm probably not doing this in the best way.

Below I'm using the word 'herps' as a test and it should return a list of all possible combinations of the word. I'm finally getting the combinations right, but they're nested and I'd like a flat list of the words. I think it's because for returns a lazy `seq`, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

```
(ns combos.core
  (:gen-class))
(use '[clojure.string :only [join]])

(defn rmletter [in letter]
    (join (remove #(= letter %) in)))

(defn combo [total in]
    (if (= (count in) 1)
        (concat total (list in))
        (for [item in] 
            (do
            (if (= (count in) 5) (print "top: "))
            (combo (concat total (list item)) (rmletter in item)))
        )))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  ;; work around dangerous default behaviour in Clojure
  (alter-var-root #'*read-eval* (constantly false))
  (doseq [item (combo nil "herps")] (print "item:")(println item))
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

And here's the output:

```
top: item:((((h e r p s) (h e r s p)) ((h e p r s) (h e p s r)) ((h e s r p) (h
e s p r))) (((h r e p s) (h r e s p)) ((h r p e s) (h r p s e)) ((h r s e p) (h
r s p e))) (((h p e r s) (h p e s r)) ((h p r e s) (h p r s e)) ((h p s e r) (h
p s r e))) (((h s e r p) (h s e p r)) ((h s r e p) (h s r p e)) ((h s p e r) (h
s p r e))))
top: item:((((e h r p s) (e h r s p)) ((e h p r s) (e h p s r)) ((e h s r p) (e
h s p r))) (((e r h p s) (e r h s p)) ((e r p h s) (e r p s h)) ((e r s h p) (e
r s p h))) (((e p h r s) (e p h s r)) ((e p r h s) (e p r s h)) ((e p s h r) (e
p s r h))) (((e s h r p) (e s h p r)) ((e s r h p) (e s r p h)) ((e s p h r) (e
s p r h))))
top: item:((((r h e p s) (r h e s p)) ((r h p e s) (r h p s e)) ((r h s e p) (r
h s p e))) (((r e h p s) (r e h s p)) ((r e p h s) (r e p s h)) ((r e s h p) (r
e s p h))) (((r p h e s) (r p h s e)) ((r p e h s) (r p e s h)) ((r p s h e) (r
p s e h))) (((r s h e p) (r s h p e)) ((r s e h p) (r s e p h)) ((r s p h e) (r
s p e h))))
top: item:((((p h e r s) (p h e s r)) ((p h r e s) (p h r s e)) ((p h s e r) (p
h s r e))) (((p e h r s) (p e h s r)) ((p e r h s) (p e r s h)) ((p e s h r) (p
e s r h))) (((p r h e s) (p r h s e)) ((p r e h s) (p r e s h)) ((p r s h e) (p
r s e h))) (((p s h e r) (p s h r e)) ((p s e h r) (p s e r h)) ((p s r h e) (p
s r e h))))
top: item:((((s h e r p) (s h e p r)) ((s h r e p) (s h r p e)) ((s h p e r) (s
h p r e))) (((s e h r p) (s e h p r)) ((s e r h p) (s e r p h)) ((s e p h r) (s
e p r h))) (((s r h e p) (s r h p e)) ((s r e h p) (s r e p h)) ((s r p h e) (s
r p e h))) (((s p h e r) (s p h r e)) ((s p e h r) (s p e r h)) ((s p r h e) (s
p r e h))))
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Check [Clojure Combinatorics lib](http://clojure.github.io/math.combinatorics/) and its [permutations](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/blob/5cf956fbc2d7225aad8e9ed8e2670e7af64417c4/src/main/clojure/clojure/math/combinatorics.clj#L158) function. Looks like it's exactly what you want.

Comment: Re: the comment in `-main`: `read` should not be used to deserialize data obtained from untrusted sources. For that, use `clojure.edn/read` in Clojure >= 1.5 and the edn reader from the `tools.reader` contrib library in earlier releases (it lives in the `clojure.tools.reader.edn` namespace). Setting `*read-eval*` to `false` is an insufficient security precaution in Clojure < 1.5, and even in Clojure >= 1.5 the "true" reader is meant for reading code and not arbitrary data and may be too capable a tool to be safe in the latter application.

Comment: Just for fun: `(take 120 (distinct (repeatedly #(shuffle (seq "ehprs")))))`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to work an `apply concat` into your answer somewhere.

A full answer to generating permutations properly is not straitforward, use [clojure.math.combinatorics](http://clojure.github.io/math.combinatorics/) if it meets your needs. It's worth describing a brief algorithm though:

```
(defn perms [v]
  (cond (= 1 (count v)) v                        ; one permutation is it's self 
        (= 2 (count v)) [[(second v) (first v)]  ; two items is [[ab][b a]]
                         [(first v) (second v)]]
        :default
        (apply concat                   
               (for [i (range (count v))]        ; take the first item     
                 (->> (assoc v i (v 0))          ; add it in each position 
                      (#(subvec % 1))            ; find the permutations of 
                      perms                      ; the rest of each of them 
                      (mapv #(conj % (nth v i)))))))) ; then stick the 
                                                 ; one that was assoced back
                                                 ; onto the start of each of them
```

There are much better ways to calulate this, this simple recursive method just strikes me as a fairly clojure way of going about the problem. One of the important points is the `assoc` call with works because it's persistent and does not clobber the version used by each of the other recursive branches.

```
hello.exp> (pprint (perms (vec "1234")))                                                                                                                                           
([\4 \3 \2 \1]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\3 \4 \2 \1]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\4 \2 \3 \1]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\2 \4 \3 \1]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\2 \3 \4 \1]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\3 \2 \4 \1]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\4 \3 \1 \2]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\3 \4 \1 \2]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\4 \1 \3 \2]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\1 \4 \3 \2]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\1 \3 \4 \2]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\3 \1 \4 \2]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\4 \1 \2 \3]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\1 \4 \2 \3]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\4 \2 \1 \3]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\2 \4 \1 \3]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\2 \1 \4 \3]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\1 \2 \4 \3]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\1 \3 \2 \4]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\3 \1 \2 \4]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\1 \2 \3 \4]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\2 \1 \3 \4]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\2 \3 \1 \4]                                                                                                                                                                     
 [\3 \2 \1 \4])                                                                                                                                                                    
nil                                                                                                                                                                                
hello.exp> (count (perms (vec "hello")))  
120
```

In practice use the lazy perm form the combinatorics library to avoid blowing the stack as this version will do.

Answer (score 1):

I love these little puzzles, and can't help but golf a bit:

```
(defn perms1 [xs]
  (if-not (next xs)
    [xs]
    (->> [[] xs]
      (iterate (fn [[a [x & b]]] ;; seq of all splits of xs
                 [(conj a x) b]))
      (take-while second)
      (mapcat (fn [[a [x & b]]]
                (map #(cons x %) ;; cons split point onto each comb of the rest
                     (perms1 (concat a b))))))))
```

Note perms1 handles duplicate items in the input collection by generating duplicate combinations in the output sequence. If we're sure of no dups in the input, we can tighten up the code a bit by using a set to hold the remaining items in the collection:

```
(defn perms2 [xs]
  (if-not (next xs)
    [xs]
    (mapcat (fn [x]
              (map cons
                   (repeat x)
                   (perms2 (disj (set xs) x))))
            xs)))
```

The nested seqs in your original solution are because your combo always returns a seq, and for always returns a seq of what its body returns, so you end up with seqs of seqs, nested to the depth of your recursion. Note how my solutions use mapcat instead of for to avoid this problem. Calling (apply concat ...) on the results of for would be another way to flatten the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

```
(defn but-nth [s i]
  [(get s i) (into [] (concat (take i s) (take-last (dec (- (count s) i)) s)))])

(defn combs [sofar r]
  (if (empty? r)
    sofar
    (for [[c z] (map (partial but-nth r) (range (count r)))]
      (combs (conj sofar c) z))))

(defn r-combs [s]
  (map (fn [x] (apply str x)) (partition (count s) (flatten (combs [] (vec s))))))

(r-combs "herps")
```